# App Preview submission, video has audio that is not two-channel

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

When submitting my App Preview, iTunes Connect says: 
"This video has audio that is not two-channel, no-surround stereo. Please refer to Apple's documentation for appropriate formats."

Well heres the catch, when I created my App Preview in iMovie, I deleted the audio track!

After giving up for a while, I came back and tried again, then I was receiving an error saying "file could not be loaded".

Each time I go to submit for review, my App Preview disappears.

Any ideas on how I can get my App Preview successfully submitted?

Comment: I assume you are using the latest Safari?

Comment: @Oddie yes, latest safari.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately "no audio channel", isn't an option in the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW14).

I'd follow the official Apple guide [over here](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/imovie/) and add some "background music":

> **Create a Soundtrack**
>
> 1. Choose File > Import Media, then select the audio file in the window that appears.
> 2. Drag music to the Background Music area at the bottom of the timeline.
> 3. Drag sound effects directly underneath any clip in the timeline.

Apple is quite picky when it comes to the allowed file formats and configurations, but once you fixed that, it should work!

Comment: Can confirm, after testing around quite a lot, Apple seem to only accept videos that actually have audio. For reference my Compressor settings were: `Stereo (L R), Sample Rate: 48kHz, Codec: AAC, Quality: Maximum, Bitrate: 256kbps` First I've exported the video with this exact settings, but without any audio tracks in the source file. Only after adding some audio I could finally upload it without issues!!

Answer (score 31):

For most apps that do not have the primary purpose of handling audio, I find background music or audio voice over to be a distraction in an app preview. If you want to add silence to preview, you can easily do it with `ffmpeg`:

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i preview.mp4 -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac previewWithSilence.mp4`

Comment: It‘s in homebrew. Install that and then ˋbrew install ffmpegˋ.

Comment: I got this error: `The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.` `Alternatively use the non experimental encoder 'libfdk_aac'.`

Comment: For some reason when I used this, the output file was almost 4 minutes long even though the video itself was about 18 seconds long. I changed the command into `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i video.mp4 -filter:v "fps=fps=30" -shortest -c:v h264 -c:a aac -r 30 app-preview.mp4`
I've read that the frame rate missing is causing this for some reason.

Answer (score 20):

If you're using iMovie:

1. Drag in any audio clip. It doesn't matter what it is.
2. Shorten the length to less than your project's total length.
3. Set the sound level to 0% by dragging the horizontal bar over the clip down.
4. Share as App Preview.